# Nancy handle request as stream to allow preemptive cancellation of file upload to save bandwidth

Tags: c#, upload, stream, nancy, bandwidth

Currently I have implemented file upload in nancy fx like that:

Client code:

```
 var testData = new byte[1024 * 1024];
 File.WriteAllBytes("testdata.bin", testData);

 var client = new WebClient();
 var res = client.UploadFile(host + "/upload", "testdata.bin");
```

Server code:

```
   public class UploadModule : NancyModule
{
    public UploadModule()
    {
        Post["/upload"] = x =>
        {
            const int userQuota = 10000;

            var file = Request.Files.Single();
            var outFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "out.bin");
            using (var outFile = File.Create(outFilePath))
            {
                var readBytesSum = 0;

                int readBytes;
                var buffer = new byte[8192];
                while ((readBytes = file.Value.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    readBytesSum += readBytes;
                    if (readBytesSum > userQuota)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Max file size exceeded!");

                    outFile.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }

                outFile.Flush();
            }

            return HttpStatusCode.OK;
        };
    }
}
```

If a user now uploads a 10 mb file the operation on the server will be canceled after all 10 mb are first recieved and then checked.

I wondered if there is a possibility in Nancy to get the request data as a stream and make a fast fail path if incoming data reaches a defined quota.
If quota is reached the connection could be dropped and no further download bandwidth on server will be wasted.

As far as I get to know is that Nancy will always buffer the whole input data either in memory or in temp file.
So I think my requirement would need more access to the low level request pipeline?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to handle request sizes at the web server level? [See here for IIS config](http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm).

Comment: Yes. I want to save bandwidth. Even with the "handle request size" setting the server would have to download the complete client request. If the client doesn't have enough quota left the server could cancel the upload directly and doesn't have to waste anymore bandwidht for this request.

Comment: also added issue on nancy project site: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2339

Comment: You should handle this before it comes to Nancy, if you're using IIS then set the limit in IIS, if you're using OWIN, then you can do it in middleware.

Comment: so that means I cant use any per user quota if it can only be handled in iis. if I would allow sending requests of 2gb I can not drop requests before recieving the full 2gb. what a pity